# IMAGE to JSON String

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am working on  a project in which I have to create both rest and mvc which will consume rest.

I have on registration form in which there is a field from which user can upload multiple image file.
After User submit the file the file is receive by my mvc controller.The Image is received as Multi-part.

I want to know How can i send this image to rest service.

I know I can use base64 to convert image to string and then send it to rest.

But I want to know, is there any way So that I can convert my image to JSon String directly.
I have tried it but it is giving me Json exception

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You could use `commons-io` library:

```
Base64.encode(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file));
```

Comment: So essentially `Base64.encode(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file));` using `commons-io` library

Comment: Yes, it's the way I would implement this ;-) Thanks for the clarification! It should have appeared clearer in my answer!